# How to create an ajax/rest application speeder and more user friendly?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, google-app-engine, rest

### The basic needs of an application

I'am working on a complete application based on Angularjs ( it could be based on any framework the question should be the same).
This application communicates to a server (based on google app engine) using rest technology.

My app allow to create appointments (it could be any type of data) and need to update the server for any creation. An appointment can be changed just after a creation.

### The Id issue

Do you know the id issue ? For me it's the **time lost** related to an object creation.

Indeed, when we create an object, the client don't know it's id until the server answered it.
Yes, how to change it after creation without the id ?
Usually, we post a $save() request (using $resource with angular, still by example) and we wait for an answer from the server which contains the new id.

And what the user can do during this time ? **Nothing ?** It's the question actually !

### The user is waiting...

You already know that i guess. Often there is a window or a message box inside the application and when you click on the button "*save*" : an ajax waiter (animated gif by example) turns until the action is finished.
In this case, it could be acceptable but imagine your app allows to create an object with a simple clic and after drag-and-drop it ? 

In my case an appointment from a day to another ? What could we do ?

### How to let the user stops to wait ?

Here actually is the question of my post : **how to remove this waiting time safely ?**
Do you know a framework of a solution to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I give a first answer to my own question but I hope for a better solution.

### User is not waiting anymore

What that means ? 
When there is a call to the server, the client don't wait the server return to give hand back.
Here the idea, is to consider that the server (which is very simple) will succeed.
Then, we just have to be sure that all "saves" are done sequentially.(still because we need the id after creation before to do next save).
Moreover, I manage a possible disconnection to the server and a retry.

### Pieces of code for a save

```
    activitySrv.save =  function(activity,successFunction,errorFunction) {
        ServerSrv.startSavingProcess(activitySrv.saveSync, activity, successFunction, errorFunction);
    }

    activitySrv.saveSync =  function(activity,successFunction,errorFunction)
    {
        var activityRes = activity.getObjectResource();
        activityRes.$save({}, //no params
            function (data) {
                $log.debug("ActivitySrv.save - success");
                $log.debug(data);
                //Save on server success :
                // -> set id for new entity and subones
                // -> add an user action (send message)
                //CallBack on success
                try {
                    activity.setId(data.id);

                    //Add user action
                    UserActionData.add(data.userAction);

                    if (successFunction !=undefined)
                        successFunction(data);
                }
                finally {
                    ServerSrv.endSavingProcess(true);
                }
            },
            function (data) {   //failure
                //error handling goes here
                $log.error("ActivitySrv.save - error");
                $log.error(data);
                try {
                    if (errorFunction !=undefined)
                        errorFunction(data);
                }
                finally {
                    ServerSrv.endSavingProcess(false,data.status);
                }
            });
    }
```

### Pieces of code of service ServerSrv

It manage a sequential process and a retry when a disconnection happens.

```
    angular.module('MyApp.services').
    factory('ServerSrv', ["$timeout","MessageSrv",
    function ($timeout,MessageSrv) {

        var  serverSrv =
        {
            nextSavesStack : [],
            delay : 5000,
            promise : null
        };
        serverSrv.addFunction =  function(functionToCall)
        {
            //Save function and parameters in order to be able to call it after current process
            var argumentsArray = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
            argumentsArray.splice(0,1);
            serverSrv.nextSavesStack.push({
                functionToCall : functionToCall,
                arguments : argumentsArray
            })
        }

        serverSrv.executeNextFunctionWithDelay=  function()
        {
            if (!serverSrv.promise)
            {
                serverSrv.promise = $timeout(serverSrv.executeNextFunction,serverSrv.delay);
                serverSrv.delay = serverSrv.delay*2;
                if (serverSrv.delay>60000)
                    serverSrv.delay = 60000;
            }

        }
        serverSrv.executeNextFunction =  function()
        {
            console.log(new Date() + " executeNextFunction ");
            if (serverSrv.promise)
                serverSrv.promise = null;
            if (serverSrv.nextSavesStack.length!=0)
            {
                var saveFunction = serverSrv.nextSavesStack[0];//remove and assign value removed to saveFunction
                saveFunction.functionToCall.apply(this, saveFunction.arguments);
            }

        }

        serverSrv.startSavingProcess =  function(functionToCall)
        {
            //Save function and parameters in order to be able to call it after current process
            var argumentsArray = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
            argumentsArray.splice(0,1);
            serverSrv.nextSavesStack.push({
                functionToCall : functionToCall,
                arguments : argumentsArray
            }) ;
            if (serverSrv.nextSavesStack.length==1)
                serverSrv.executeNextFunction();
        }
        serverSrv.endSavingProcess =  function(isSuccess,errorCode)
        {
            var mustRetry = false;
            if (isSuccess)
            {
                MessageSrv.cleanMessage();
                serverSrv.delay = 5000;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (errorCode) {
                    case 404:
                        MessageSrv.send("error","Connexion error<br/>New try in " + serverSrv.delay/1000 + "s");
                        mustRetry = true;
                        break;
                    case 403:
                        MessageSrv.send("error","Access not allowed");
                        break;
                    case 409:
                        //Not found do nothing ?
                        break;
                    default:
                        MessageSrv.send("error","Error n°"+errorCode);
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (mustRetry)
                serverSrv.executeNextFunctionWithDelay();
            else
            {
                serverSrv.nextSavesStack.splice(0,1);
                serverSrv.executeNextFunction();
            }
        }

        return serverSrv;

    }]);
```